# I want to update the currentAuthenticatedUser and attributes using the access_token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, authentication, oauth-2.0, access-token

I have already get the access Token and user information using the API end point but now I want to login into please help me how I can login into and get currentAuthenticatedUser, I have not login with user and pass word because I have using Facebook/Google Web UI login into aws.

```
Hub.listen("auth", ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
  switch (event) {
    case "signIn":
      Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user => {
        this.setState({ user, error: null, loading: false });
        debugger
      });
      break;
    case "signOut":
      this.setState({ user: null, error: null, loading: false });
       debugger
      break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try below code, it may be work for you:**

`

```
componentDidMount() {
    Hub.listen('auth', this);
}

onHubCapsule(capsule) {
  debugger
    const { channel, payload, source } = capsule;
    if (channel === 'auth' && payload.event === 'signIn') { 
      this.checkUser();
   }else{
    this.setState({user :  null});
   }
}

checkUser() {
     Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then((user) => {
      this.setState(user)
     });
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```js
    Hub.listen("auth", async ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
      switch (event) {
        case "signIn": {
          this.setState({ user: data,error: null, loading: false });
          break;
        }
        case "signOut": {
          this.setState({ user: null, error: null, loading: false });
          break;
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @hong, but this method return user==null, because user not login into Auth.

Comment: I have update my question please look the code, Hub.listen always return signOut case for me.